# java programme like a winamp select file

Tags: java, swing, multi-select, jfilechooser

can the users select one or more than one mp3 files using JFileChooser?

I can only select user one file , using this method.

Answer (score 6):

Just set the multi-selection to true and the selection mode to JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES and it will work for a multiple files and all the files in a directory:

```
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES );
fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
```

Then retrieve all the files this way:

```
fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
```

Comment: meddle, at this time the code doesnt compiles. i cant add one file anymore

Comment: @zenx: `fileChooser.getSelectedFiles()` returns `File[]`, so you need to modify your code appropriately.

Comment: You said the code didn't compile, can you paste the changed code for selecting multiple files.

Comment: @zenx: maybe you should consider editing your question and posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) version of your code. That way, all your comments above would make sense to someone.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of your requirement is:

- User can choose one or multiple files
- If a single file is chosen, then you work with that file
- If multiple files are chosen then you would create a playlist and work with this playlist.

If this is what you want, I think the following might work for this scenario. Note that I've left the implementation to you because you know how to create a playlist or how to create a single file and feed it to your player.

```
/** This method returns a set of files chosen by the user. 
  * Returns null if selection is cancelled 
  **/
private File[] openFiles(){

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES );

    int optionChosen = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    return (optionChosen == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) ? null : fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    File[] selectedFiles = openFiles();

    if(selectedFiles == null){
       //handleNoFileChosen
    }else if(selectedFiles.length == 1){
        //handle single file selected
    }else{
        //handle creating playlist
    }
}
```